# Kali 2020.4 File system empty

Tags: kali-linux

So I am new to Kali and installed 2020.4 x64 on vmware workstation. I used `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` for updates, and after i logged back in, I can no longer see any folders, files etc. through the file system. I can find the files via terminal, but the file system app is not showing anything. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have that very same configuration here and posting from within Kali.

Restart Kali (not the host) and at the Login Screen, use Ctrl-Alt-F1 to get a terminal login.

Once logged in:   sudo apt autoremove  .

Allow Autoremove to work and finish.

Restart Kali and log in normally.

I have done this before and it works for me (only had issues once or twice a while back) and hopefully it will work for you.